# Django MySql InternalError: (-1, 'server not initialized')

Tags: python, django, mysql-python

I have had this working, a few months ago, but apparently I phases of the moon changed or something.
I have MySQL-python installed.
And I only get this error when running `manage.py shell` and then trying to make db queries. When I add or remove items from the `/admin/` interface then it doesn't seem to have any troubles.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home2/univetg1/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 151, in get
    return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home2/univetg1/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 301, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home2/univetg1/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 77, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home2/univetg1/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 854, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home2/univetg1/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/home2/univetg1/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 710, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/home2/univetg1/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 780, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/home2/univetg1/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 157, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/home2/univetg1/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 129, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home2/univetg1/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 124, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home2/univetg1/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home2/univetg1/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 124, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home2/univetg1/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 112, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home2/univetg1/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 435, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home2/univetg1/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home2/univetg1/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    client_version = tuple([ numeric_part(n) for n in _mysql.get_client_info().split('.')[:2] ])
InternalError: (-1, 'server not initialized')
```

my db settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a MySQL server running? What db settings are you using?

Comment: Nothing complicated. I just added the the database settings above. I can access the database through the /admin/ pages so I am assuming that the database is online.